# How to restore deleted Order in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

I have deleted an order accidentally. It's very important to recover this order However I do not know how to recover deleted order. I am using magento 1.9.2 version. Kindly help me.

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely you will be able to extract all the data for a single order from your sql backup and import it back to your live db. I usually have a dev version of my live site on a virtual server, i would restore the database to my dev server and access the order info from there.

Comment: You won't be able to recover it without reverting the database.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. AFAIK, there is no way to recover a delete order. My solution was to restore the database from backup to a staging server, then fulfill the deleted orders there.